# Convert an Excel column of emails into a list with very specific formatting

Tags: excel, csv, data-manipulation

I need an efficient way to convert a **large** number of emails from a mailing list spreadsheet into a list of emails.

For example, my spreadsheet would have a column of names, emails, and perhaps other data that isn't relevant:

```
Name1 | email1@email.com  
Name2 | email2@email.com  
Name3 | email3@email.com
```

And I'd like to get a list like this:

```
name1@email.com, name2@email.com, name3@email.com
```

I need my output to be a simple list with commas, no quotation marks or other marks except the commas. Spaces are ok. I'm expecting python to be best for this, though I also have some experience with R and RStudio.

Previously what I've been doing is copying the whole column of emails, heading over to a new spreadsheet, doing paste, paste special, transpose, which pastes them across 1 row. Then I saved as a CSV, opened up the csv in a text editor, and copied the list from there. It seems like there must be a better, more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TEXTJOIN` for this.

Suppose your emails are in `B2:B100`, then:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:B100)
```

You can use whatever delimiter you want in the first argument.